# Cell of UICollectionViewController doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Xcode 9.2, Swift 4
I have a CollectionViewController scene in my Main.storyboard that I linked to CollectionVewController class.
In this scene there is a cell, whose the identifier is TextCell. I changed the background color of this one directly in the Main.storyboard.

Here is the code of my CollectionViewControllerClass

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "TextCell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52.0 / 250.0, green: 63.0 / 250.0, blue: 77.0 / 250.0, alpha: 1)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

I don't see any cell when I run the app, does someone know why ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

That line tells the runtime *not* get the cell from the storyboard. But you *do* want to get the cell from the storyboard, because that is where you changed the background color of the cell.